# RocksDB Converting SST Files to Human-Readable Text

Tags: rocksdb

I possess a folder named **myfolder** which contains the following types of files:

- sst files
- log files
- CURRENT file
- IDENTITY file
- LOCK file
- LOG files
- MANIFEST files
- OPTIONS files

The output of the command:

> sst_dump --file=myfolder --show_properties

is as follows:

```
from [] to []
Process myfolder/000123.sst
Sst file format: block-based
Table Properties:
------------------------------
  # data blocks: 4
  # entries: 4
  # range deletions: 0
  raw key size: 136
  raw average key size: 34.000000
  raw value size: 26696032
  raw average value size: 6674008.000000
  data block size: 26696244
  index block size (user-key? 0, delta-value? 0): 105
  filter block size: 69
  (estimated) table size: 26696418
  filter policy name: rocksdb.BuiltinBloomFilter
  prefix extractor name: nullptr
  column family ID: 1
  column family name: keypoints_and_descriptors
  comparator name: leveldb.BytewiseComparator
  merge operator name: nullptr
  property collectors names: []
  SST file compression algo: Snappy
  creation time: 1691400030
  time stamp of earliest key: 0
  # deleted keys: 0
  # merge operands: 0
Raw user collected properties
------------------------------
  # rocksdb.block.based.table.index.type: 0x00000000
  # rocksdb.block.based.table.prefix.filtering: 0x30
  # rocksdb.block.based.table.whole.key.filtering: 0x31
  # rocksdb.deleted.keys: 0x00
  # rocksdb.merge.operands: 0x00
```

Note that I encountered a segmentation fault when attempting the following command:

> sst_dump --file=myfolder --command=raw

I am seeking advice on how to convert these files into human-readable text files. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note that I face the below error at the end of the LOG file:

```
2023/08/08-21:29:22.970091 7f2d9e083340 [db/db_impl.cc:365] Shutdown: canceling all background work
2023/08/08-21:29:22.970328 7f2d9e083340 [db/db_impl_files.cc:273] [JOB 10] Tried to delete a non-existing file /home/user/matching_working///OPTIONS-000010 type=9 #10 -- IO error: while unlink() file: /home/user/matching_working///OPTIONS-000010: No such file or directory
2023/08/08-21:29:22.970520 7f2d9e083340 [db/db_impl.cc:521] Shutdown complete
```

Thanks in advance